# WordPress 4.2.3 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Creating Files as read only

Tags: php, plugin-w3-total-cache

Whenever I attempt to update a plugin or change my configuration for W3 Total Cache, if wordpress creates a new file, it's created with the Read Only attribute. I can upload and delete content without issue. It's just updating a plugin or the w3total cache config. I removed the read only attribute from the w3 total cache config file and the changes are saved successfully, subsequent updates fail because the newly created config file is read only. I've confirmed it's PHP-CGI that's changing the attribute, because on the successful config update I see PHP-CGI changing the attribute. I've tried every combination of permissions / ownership I could think of. Including using AppPool identities and "Connect As", running as administrators and non-admins. I'm just not sure why the read only attribute is getting set.

![Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR7Ph.png

Comment: I had an issue where files were inheriting the permissions of the temp directory. The fix was to change the path of the `upload_tmp_dir` in php.ini to a folder that has the same permissions as your plugins folder

Comment: WP on MS - I feel for your pain, mate.

Comment: Yeah no go on the tmp directory. None of my folders are set to inherit permissions, and the app pool user is the owner.  I just dont understand why WP is applying that Read Only attribute only on plugin updates / config changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, my site had the following in wp-config.php. Also WP-config.php had to be placed at the site root

```
 define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', true );
 define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', true );
 define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Removing the above resolved the issue.